# Can TCP stand for "Transport Control Protocol"

Tags: tcp, transport-protocol, layer4, terminology

I know it might sound like a silly question, but afaik TCP stands for transmission control protocol. However I found a couple of websites using the term Transport Control Protocol.

So I was wondering if they're wrong or if there is any source/reference for using the term "transport"?

Here's an example of 2 websites refering to TCP as Transport Control Protocol

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/transport-control-protocol

And page 12/13 (slide 68)
https://perso.univ-lyon1.fr/olivier.gluck/Cours/Supports/L3IF_RE/RE-P2-Bases.pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: The definition of TCP is in _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guys who defined it called it [Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) only. The others seem to have it mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

"Transport" in place of "Transmission" just looks like a mistake.

However, in some early documents "TCP" is used to mean "Transmission Control *Program*" not "Protocol", as you can see in [RFC 675](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc675), written by Cerf et al and dated December 1974.

Both earlier and current documents use "Transmission" uniquely:

- "Protocol" is used in Cerf and Kahn's slightly earlier landmark paper "[A protocol for packet network intercommunication](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos561/papers/cerf74.pdf)", published May 1974 in (*IEEE Transactions on Communication*, vol. C-
  2O, No. 5. May 1974, pp. 637-648.)
- The standard as we now know it, [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), uses "Protocol".  This was published in 1981 and it is only attributed to the "Information Sciences Institute", though  editor Postel describes it as having many authors.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information on protocol/program confusion.